# How to make equal height DIVs with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to make a jQuery function that cycles through all `<div class="check-js"></div>`, compare the heights to find out the tallest, and set them all at the same height as the tallest one, but this doesn't seem to be working. What might be the problem in this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $('.check-js').each(function() {
                    alert($(this).index);
                    var aux = 0;
                    var max = 0;
                    aux = $(this).style.height;
                    aux.replace(/\D/g,'');
                    alert(max);
                    if (Math.max(aux, max)==aux){
                        max = aux;
                    }
                });
            });
```

This isn't finished I haven't add the instruction to change the heights, because I couldn't make it cycle through the `<div>`s, the alert of `max` doesn't pop up.

Comment: can you add this code on jsfiddle with html element?

Comment: You are re-declaring your `max` variable everytime it loops, move that outside the `.each`

Comment: Yeah I noticed that mistake, but that wasn't the issue here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a shared variable `max` else in every iteration the value of `max` will get reseted... also to get the height of an element use [.height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //shared variable
    var max = 0,
        $els = $('.check-js');
    $els.each(function () {
        max = Math.max($(this).height(), max); //use height method from jQuery
    });

    $els.height(max)
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cvpswteg/4/)

Comment: O wow how silly of me to leave the max variable get reseted on each loop. Yes your solution seems to work, but why do we have to do this $els = $('.check-js'); in order to work, why does my method won't work?

Comment: @TiagoMartins that is just used to cache the value since we want to reuse  it again to set the height

Comment: @TiagoMartins you could also do `var max = 0;
    $('.check-js').each(function () {
        max = Math.max($(this).height(), max); //use height method from jQuery
    }).height(max);`

Answer (score 1):

First off, because you are cycling through them you can't compare them without variables outside of the `each` scope. Heres a simple way to find the highest with `jQuerys` each loop/function:

```
function findHighest(jQueryObjects){
    var highest = 0;
    jQueryObjects.each(function(){
        var localHeight = $(this).innerHeight();
        if(localHeight > highest){
            highest = localHeight;
        }
    });
    return highest;
}
```

Now you could do `$('.check-js').css("height", findHighest($('.check-js')));` to apply the highest height to each (although it would be *better* to declare it in a variable first: `var height = findHighest($('.check-js')); $('.check-js').css("height", height);`);

Comment: This is also a neat method, does this function is already defined in JQuery or should I create a file named functions and add it there?

Comment: @tiagomartins You should add it, its not defined by jquery. :)